# Significance of passing a function as an argument

Tags: c++

I just learn about passing a function of as an argument in c++,
however I wonder what is its significance.

Considering this example,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void argumentFunction(int x) {
      cout << x << " is the result.";
}

void myFunction(void (*functionparam) (int), char parameter[80]) {
    cout << parameter;
    (*functionparam)(1);
}

int main() {
    myFunction(&argumentFunction, "I am calling a function with a function.");      
    cin.ignore(80,'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

why would I need to pass argumentFunction as a parameter in myFunction, which in fact I can directly call it without passing it:

like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void argumentFunction(int x) {
      cout << x << " is the result.";
}

void myFunction(char parameter[80]) {
    cout << parameter;
    argumentFunction(1);
}

int main() {
    myFunction( "I am calling a function with a function.");        
    cin.ignore(80,'\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, note that in C++ a pointer to a function is *usually* a mistake. You usually want to define the behavior in a virtual function or a template parameter instead. A virtual function pretty much *is* a pointer to a function, but gives a cleaner (type-based) interface to the same capability. A template parameter is also type-based, but adds more versatility so you can accept things like the closure from a lambda expression in addition to actual pointers to functions. It also frequently improves optimization (easier to generate inline code).

Answer (score 7):

One example is in the C standard library function [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), which has the signature:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
    int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

This allows the programmer to pass an arbitrary comparison function to the existing sorting algorithm instead of having to write a whole new sort function for each type of sorting that needs to be done.

Comment: So I think passing a function as an argument is a practice of C style. In C++ we usually use templates and classes with virtual functions for the same purpose.

Comment: @jangler yes I encounter the qsort function in C, I just know how to call and use them but I dont really know how they are implemented.. thanks ..

Answer (score 4):

If we take a practical example like C's `qsort`, it doesn't know how to compare your data. After all, it could be string keys you're sorting, integers, floats, pointers, a combo, etc.

It knows how to sort your data, but it doesn't know how to compare one of your keys to another. So passing in a comparator function pointer gives it that missing puzzle piece and allows that code to sort virtually anything (well, except for objects that require C++ semantics since it just shuffles bytes around while ignoring objects).

So a function pointer is a useful mechanism for decoupling. `qsort` is decoupled from the data types it can potentially sort. That also makes it very generally applicable since you can provide the missing functionality it needs by passing in function pointers.

Another example is, say, you want to build a user interface for a software. Whenever the data in your software changes, some viewport/canvas kind of thingy should be redrawn. If you just called that redraw function directly in every part of your codebase where the data changes, all sorts of parts throughout your system would have to be coupled to the user interface.

Instead, if the system just calls one or more function pointers whenever the data changes, the underlying system doesn't have to be directly coupled to anything in the user interface (also allowing you to swap out the user interface with something newer and more fashionable without breaking that logic). It's sort of like broadcasting a signal out to the world saying, "I have changed!" without caring who is listening, and we can pass in the appropriate function pointers to determine what to do in the case of such events.

With C++ you have more flexible concepts like virtual functions, functionoids using them, function objects that work with templates, ones that can work abstractly using templates to capture specific function object types through static polymorphism to something using dynamic polymorphism that doesn't require templates to then be used, etc. But it's basically the same idea.

Comment: thanks for clarification, as a beginner in c++ I may not be able to understand some of the things that you've mention like virtual functions and functionoids , however i recognize that this feature is very useful indeed.  thanks again